# PHP mysql form , STUCK

Tags: php, mysql

Ok please if anyone could help with this simple php and mysql question.

I'm new to databases, and trying to create my first user-friendly database. but i ran in to small problem.

I have a page that displays data, Than I also have a page where same data is displayed along with edit link, that goes to the edit form. However in the edit form the info is not coming up.

Here is my "edit.php" it shows info from database along with edit link:

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("beyondmotors", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Mileage</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['mileage'] . "</td>";
      echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($con);
```

And here is the Edit form :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Form Edit Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td align=center>Form Edit Employees Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
          <?
          $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("beyondmotors", $con);
          $order = "SELECT * FROM vehicles where id=$id";
          $result = mysql_query($order);
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          ?>
          <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>">
            <tr>        
              <td>Year</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="year" 
            size="20" value="<? echo "$row[year]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
              <td>Make</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="make" 
            size="20" value="<? echo "$row[make]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
              <td>Model</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="model" 
            size="20" value="<? echo "$row[model]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mileage</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="mileage" 
              value="<? echo "$row[mileage]"?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" 
              name="submit value" value="Edit">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </form>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Than I also have Edit data, but it doesnt even get to that. Here is what i get at the edit form!! http://s562.photobucket.com/albums/ss69/intensemx/?action=view&current=pic.jpg

I followed **[this](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P284.html)** tutorial :

Help i'm lost here, Thanks in advance :)

Can any one recommend good place where I can get a similar tutorial.

Comment: Where in the edit form have you assigned the `$id` variable? Somewhere you should have something like `$id = $_GET['id']`

Comment: @Brendan Bullen — register_globals

Comment: @Quentin As yes. That attrocity. Forgot about that one. :)

Comment: That's not nearly a title.  Please [edit] and fix.

Answer (score 7):

The tutorial you are using is assuming that [short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) are turned on. Alter the code to use `<?php` instead.

It also suffers from an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com/).

It also appears to assume that [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is turned on.

**Do not use that tutorial. It is dangerously bad.**

Comment: I thought it might be ancient, but no - as recent as March 2008. Oh dear! (I've tried to leave a comment about its flaws, but it may be stuck in moderation - and of course they may not publish it anyway).

Comment: +1 for the answer and for highlighting just how bad that tutorial is.

Comment: Changed the tags to allow short tags, turned on register_global, still same response, I did notice the tutorial was bad, few things i had go around. Could you please recommend a place where I can get a similar , more recent version? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your array keys in quotes. For example, this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>">
```

Should be this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $row['id']?>">
```

Now, besides that, please consider the problems mention by Quentin in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit form uses PHP Short Tags (`<? ?>`) which are probably not enabled on your server, so everything looks wrong.

Your options to fix it are to 1) Enable short tags, or 2) change `<?` to `<?php` in your edit file.