# Need assistance with a php mysql UPDATE statement tutorial please

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Trying to follow a tutorial, but i get a database error on line six of the executable php file (second code below)

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error: ".mysql_error()); //add your DB                          username and password
    mysql_select_db("beyondmotors");//add your dbname

    $sql = "select * from `TestTable` where ID = 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $id = $row['ID'];
        $fname = $row['FName'];
        $lname = $row['LName'];
        $phone = $row['PHON'];

        //we will echo these into the proper fields

    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Edit User Info</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="updateinfo.php" method="post">

    userid:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" name="id" disabled/>

    <br/>

    Last Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" name="fname"/>

    <br/>

    Last Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lname;?>" name="lname"/>

    <br/>

    Phone Number:<br/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $phone;?>" name="phon"/>

    </br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit changes"/>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is the executable

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Error: ".mysql_error()); //add your DB                 username and password
    mysql_se lect_db("beyondmotors");//add your dbname

    //get the variables we transmitted from the form
    $id = $_POST[''];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $phon = $_POST['phon'];

    //replace TestTable with the name of your table
    $sql = "UPDATE `TestTable` SET `FName` = '$fname',`LName` = '$lname',
        `PHON` = '$phon' WHERE `TestTable`.`ID` = '$id' LIMIT 1";

    mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    echo "Database updated. <a href='editinfo.php'>Return to edit info</a>";
    ?>
```

everything is good until i hit submit changes; than i get error on line 6. I'm new to database so please be specific if possible. Thank you! also if anyone could point me to a similar, "working" tutorial that would help ALOT!

trying to follow this tutorial: http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/editing-mysql-data-using-php

i'm using wamp server, so the database log in is correct. I mean it displays the data, just doesn't edit it..
The error i'm getting is :

Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\wamp\www\test\updateinfo.php on line 6

i get that even if i change post to $id = $_POST['ID'];

Ok I changed the $_POST['']; to $_POST['id']; , still had the same error.

Than I read online to add a @ to the front so now it looks like this: @$_POST['id'];

That too off all the errors. but not my data base is not been updated. Everything goes through with no errors but no data is been changed??

Also when i tried to remove backticks I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\test\updateinfo.php on line 12

So i left them the way they were...

Could it be because i'm using a local server? This should be all simple not sure what i'm doing wrong here.. I mean i literary copied everything over from the tutorial.

Comment: and of course this is susceptible sql injection attack.

Comment: Is the user for your database actually `root` with no password? If not, you'll need to insert the actual username and password as the second and third parameters for `mysql_connect` at the beginning of the script (it's called a script, not an executable).

Comment: And, is there a reason you set `$id = $_POST['']`? The bit between the quotes should be the name of the field you want it to get the ID from (just like you have `'fname'` corresponding to the fname field in your form, and so forth).

Comment: All @ does is SUPPRESS error messages, it doesn't magically fix them. If you're getting a T_STRING error your quotes are probably off. Paste the EXACT code you're using for `$sql =  ` Also, you don't have to update your original post every time you answer a comment. you can use comments as well by clicking `add comment`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mysql form , STUCK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741570/php-mysql-form-stuck)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you should be warned that your code is completely vulnerable against [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). [Escaping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your POST data before inserting it into the database is a good start in protecting your database.

Also, learning the [mysql extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) is useless for new systems because it is deprecated. You might think about looking into the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) interface or the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension. There are many [beginner tutorials](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/4995-beginners-guide-to-pdo/) for both and you will gain much more.

###Now, as for your error###
Make sure you are defining which ID you want to update in your database. In your second block of code you have:

```
//get the variables we transmitted from the form
$id = $_POST[''];
```

needs to change to:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

You said you  get the error even if you change post to `$id = $_POST['ID']`, but if you look at your form, the id input has `name = 'id'` and PHP is case sensitive.

Now, in your sql query, all of those back ticks are unnecessary. Also, there is no point in specifying which table ID because this is all being done in ONE table, TestTable.

```
//replace TestTable with the name of your table
$sql = "UPDATE TestTable SET FName = '$fname',LName = '$lname', 
        PHON = '$phon' WHERE ID = '$id' LIMIT 1";
```

**EDIT:**
Although the query above is syntactically correct, you should consider using mysqli or PDO due to reasons mentioned above. Below are examples using mysqli and PDO.

##Mysqli##

[mysqli Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
/* connect to the database */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

/* build prepared statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE TestTable SET FName=?, LName=?, PHON=? WHERE ID=?)");

/* bind your parameters */
$stmt->bind_param('sssi', $fname, $lname, $phon, $id);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* close connection */
$stmt->close();
```

##PDO##

[PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
/* connect to the database */
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $user, $pass);

/* build prepared statement */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE TestTable SET FName = :fname, LName = :lname, PHON = :phon WHERE ID = :id");

/* bind your parameters */
$stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lname);
$stmt->bindParam(':phon', $phon);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

/* update one row */
$fname = 'John'; # or use your $_POST data
$lname = 'Doe';
$phon  = '123-456-7890';
$id    = 1;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* use it again!1! */
$fname = 'Jane';
$lname = 'Doe';
$phon  = '123-456-7890';
$id    = 2;

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* close connection */
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: Don't forget to add filter and escape to your values. I know you advised it but its not in your code

Comment: @Baba better yet, i just added examples of using mysqli and PDO :]

Answer (score 0):

Remove backticks:

```
UPDATE TestTable SET FName = '$fname',LName = '$lname',PHON ='$phon' 
WHERE TestTable.ID = '$id' LIMIT 1";
```